# Configure proxy for node connection

Tags: node

I am having my system running behind a proxy. After setting the proxy settings for the docker, I managed to install and run an Alphanet node. The problem is that I cannot get this node synchronize or even connect to any other node (even using the suggested scripts in other posts).

I also get a warning in the node log saying

> Warning: cannot resolve "boot.tzalpha.net"
>
> Warning: cannot resolve "bootalpha.tzbeta.net"

and then constantly the too few connections(0) warning

> p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (0)

This is what I get when trying to connect the node to other peers using the tezos-admin-client:
[image]

I guess the node has no internet connection because of the missing proxy settings.
Is there any way to configure the proxy settings for the tezos alphanet node?

Comment: Please share the exact docker configuration as well as the full proxy settings. Did you try to resolve the domains or any domain manually from within the docker container? This seems to be a general configuration issue not necessarily a tezos node issue.

Comment: I tried to set up and run the node after compiling from sources (without using the docker). The proxy is configured using two environmental variables (http_proxy and https_proxy) and I verified that I have full internet access from within the terminal. When running the tezos-node (compiled from sources), the two warnings
(Warning: cannot resolve "boot.tzalpha.net"
& Warning: cannot resolve "bootalpha.tzbeta.net")
do not occur anymore, but the too few connections(0) warnings persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tezos node cannot run behind an HTTP proxy. The Tezos peer to peer protocol is a proprietary protocol, and not standard HTTP. You’ll need to allow direct outbound connections from port 9732 TCP in order for the Tezos node to connect to the rest of the Tezos network.